# How to get a Object to controller part without ng-model if parameter as in ng-change..?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat for iterating a list objects.when select one option then I wanna that object not single variable value and also not using ng-model.because ng-model have to only id.I want to pass subapp object in whenClick(subapp)

http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1416/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker"  data-live-search="true"   ng-model="subappData"  id="subapplicationid" style="height: 21px;width: 300px;-moz-margin-start: 132px;margin-left: 138px;margin-top: 2px;-moz-margun-start: 132px;">
         <option value="">Select</option>
      <option  ng-repeat='subapp in subapplicationList | filter:query' data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}" value = "{{subapp.ID}}"> <a href="#"> {{subapp.ID}} - {{subapp.DESCRIPCION}} </a> </option>
               </select>
    <div>                   
   <div>
    <button  ng-click="whenClick()">Click</button>
   </div>     
    </div>  
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.subapplicationList = [
  {"ID" :  9 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "a","value" : 24 },
  {"ID" :  1 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "b","value" : 7 },
  {"ID" :  2 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "c","value" : 12 },
  {"ID" :  3 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "d","value" : 2 },
  ];
   $scope.whenClick = function() {
   alert(JSON.stringify($scope.subappData));
  };
});
myapp.directive('selectWatcher', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var last = attr.last;
            if (last === "true") {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('val', 1);
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('refresh');

                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you want to pass select variable into function ng-click? Can you give more information in your question? I don't get your problem now.

Comment: I want pass object as subapp in ng-change but selected variable id assign to ng-model